# Convert String to org.w3c.dom Document

Tags: java, xml

I am receiving this string via servlet from javascript as such :

```
 %3C%3Fxml+version%3D%221.0%22+encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22+standalone%3D%22no%22%3F%3E%3Crunningparameters%3E++%0A%09%3Caccesskey%3Eawd%3C%2Faccesskey%3E%0A%09%3Csecretkey%3ErL8cuC6GzH%2F8zHycg45sM47MqQMVVPmgZjdgDIJS%3C%2Fsecretkey%3E%0A%09%3Ckeyfile%3E%2FTdcGooglePrototype%2Fresources%2Ffrank_arianit_keypair.pem%3C%2Fkeyfile%3E%0A%09%3Creadybucketname%3Efa-initialbucket%3C%2Freadybucketname%3E%0A%09%3Cdonebucketname%3Efa-completedbucket%3C%2Fdonebucketname%3E%0A%09%3Cmanagertodownloader%3Ehttps%3A%2F%2Fsqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com%2F210890795349%2FFA_M2D%0A%09%3C%2Fmanagertodownloader%3E%0A%09%3Capplicationtomanager%3Ehttps%3A%2F%2Fsqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com%2F210890795349%2FFA_A2M%0A%09%3C%2Fapplicationtomanager%3E%0A%09%3Cpolicyconfig%3Ehttps%3A%2F%2Fsqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com%2F210890795349%2FFA_Policy%0A%09%3C%2Fpolicyconfig%3E%0A%09%3Cqueuelength%3E100%3C%2Fqueuelength%3E%0A%09%3Cnumberofdownloader%3E100%3C%2Fnumberofdownloader%3E%0A%09%3Cdownloadspeed%3E10%3C%2Fdownloadspeed%3E%0A%09%3Cpagerankthreshold%3E0.001%3C%2Fpagerankthreshold%3E%0A%09%3Ctotalpages%3E10000%3C%2Ftotalpages%3E%0A%09%3Cpagerankmaxloop%3E10%3C%2Fpagerankmaxloop%3E%0A%09%3Ccountryfilters%3E%0A%09%09%3Curlcountry%3Ecom%3C%2Furlcountry%3E%0A%09%3C%2Fcountryfilters%3E%0A%09%3Cfiletypefilters%3E++++++%0A%09%09%3Curlfiletype%3Epdf%3C%2Furlfiletype%3E%0A%09%09%3Curlfiletype%3Ehtml%3C%2Furlfiletype%3E++%0A%09%09%3Curlfiletype%3Ehtm%3C%2Furlfiletype%3E%0A%09%3C%2Ffiletypefilters%3E%0A%09%3Cseedurls%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Curl%3Ehttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.cnn.com%2F%3C%2Furl%3E+%09%0A%09%3C%2Fseedurls%3E%0A%3C%2Frunningparameters%3E
```

It's in xml but kinda look messed up. Is there a way to convert this to dom document ?

I tried :

```
Document d;
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder parser = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
d = parser.parse(xmlstring);
```

But it doesn't work because i know the string format looks crazy.

Comment: You need to URL-decode it.

Comment: Following on what @Slaks just said...  The encoding you're looking at is [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), probably better known as URL encoding, and is defined in [RFC-3986, section 2.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.1).  It is typically used to include reserved ("illegal") characters in a URL, such as when one URL must contain another (for example: `href="/redirect?newUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fsome.other.site%2F/"`).  I don't know if Java has a percent encoder / decoder in the standard JDK or not.